# Stop suggest autocomplete list from showing when combobox list is opened?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a datagrid with some combobox columns. I want user to type with suggestions or to choose from list.

It now works fine but if you open the list and then start typing and press Enter, then no events I use for row checking are not fired.

How can I disable suggestion list when there is a combobox's one?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to include

```
autocomplete="off"
```

in your element. ie:

```
<input type="text" id="myInputBox" name="myInputBox" autocomplete="off" value="initialValue"/>
```

So, basicaly you'll need to update your grid code to create inputs with this attribute included. You'll need to override a few methods. 'ıll try to post msdn links..

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution:

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox c = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            c.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            c.MaxDropDownItems = 100;
            c.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(c_KeyPress);




        }
    }

void c_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as ComboBox).DroppedDown = false;
    }
```